# IBM Worklight - IOS “Downloading Application update” dialog stuck while app is updating

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am having 2 applications which I wanted to run on different ports, I have created two different instances of Liberty core (for e.g SimpleServer & SimpleServer2) doing that I was able to deploy 2 different applications on different port. The application on SimpleServer is working and updating fine But in case of the application on SimpleServer2 I am having the  following problem.

I have created and deployed an worklight iPad application on WL server. whenever we update .wlapp on the server it asks for update on iPad and we can download the updates.
But in my case the dialog appears for downloading and never goes off, I can see progress bar fully completed, but it is stuck on downloading.

**What could be the possible reasons for this behavior?**

We are deploying the application in a production environment, and
The worklight versions and build no's are:

WL Server version: 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630

Server build number: 20131126-0630

Development  platform version: 6.1.0.01.20140718-1711

Development  platform build number: 20140718-1711

[updated]
Here is the log from the device.

```
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 0 to 8388608  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['WebResourcesDownloader'] took '21.173828' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Start downloading update file.  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 0  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 0  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 0  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 0  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 0  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] defaultOptions:onSuccess  
Oct 15 15:58:45 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 0  
Oct 15 15:58:46 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 2561  
Oct 15 15:58:46 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 2561  
Oct 15 15:58:46 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 8247  
Oct 15 15:59:07 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3105399  
Oct 15 15:59:07 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3136667  
Oct 15 15:59:07 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3142006  
Oct 15 15:59:09 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3525922  
Oct 15 15:59:10 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3558270  
Oct 15 15:59:10 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3558270  
Oct 15 15:59:10 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3558270  
Oct 15 15:59:10 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3558270  
Oct 15 15:59:10 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 3558270  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4749858  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 4767836 to 13156444  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Start downloading update file.  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836    
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4767836  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 4768610   to 13157218  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Start downloading update file.  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610    
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:20 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768610  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 4768620   to 13157228  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Start downloading update file.  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 4768620 to 13157228  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Start downloading update file.  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620  
Oct 15 15:59:21 My-iPad NDIApp[3759] <Warning>: Length of update file is: 4768620
```

after this it goes in endless loop. it stuck on file 4768620

Comment: Add the following missing information: Worklight Studio and Worklight Server full version and build number. As as well as mention if this is happening in a development environment or only/also in a production/test environment, and anything else like scenario and other information not mentioned.

Comment: Sanket, you should update BOTH your development AND production environments to use the LATEST version of 6.1. This means to the very latest version available from IBM Fix Central. Additionally, your development environment is more than a YEAR newer than your production environment. That is not serious. Upgrade, both.

Comment: Idan Thanks for the reply. I will update both the environments but there is another application deployed on the same environment which is working fine. To give you the scenario I updated the question

Comment: Is that question relates to your Direct Update issue? Look in the generated native project and make sure that in worklight.plist it points to the correct address.

Comment: yes that question is related to Direct Update issue. I have also verified the worklight.plist it pointing to the correct address

Comment: Update the studio and server to match the same version in both development and production and re-install the applications and .war, etc. See if it will still happen.

Comment: just to give more information I have added the logs from device

Comment: Also confirm that you're now using the latest Studio version as well as server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
On the worklight server version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630  
After applying Fix Pack 6.1.0-WL-WCE-FP001 and 6.1.0-WL-WCE-FP002  
Worklight Server got upgraded to:  
version=6.1.0  
fixpack=01  
buildNumber=20140821-0406
```

Direct update feature started working.